# Passing complex objects to Q# operations

Tags: python, json, q#

I want to pass a complex object to a Q# operation from Python code. I defined the same data structure on both sides: in Python as a *class* and in Q# as a *newtype*.
Than I prepared a JSON representation in Python of the complex object (exploiting the **json** package and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35483750/14426869)) and tried to pass it to a Q# operation, but I got the following error:

```
Received invalid parameters. Please fix and try again:
n: Unexpected initial token 'String' when populating object. Expected JSON object or array. Path '', line 1, position 171.
```

This is the Python code

```
import qsharp
import json
import inspect

from json.test import JsonTest

class ObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, "to_json"):
            return self.default(obj.to_json())
        elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
            d = dict(
                (key, value)
                for key, value in inspect.getmembers(obj)
                if not key.startswith("__")
                and not inspect.isabstract(value)
                and not inspect.isbuiltin(value)
                and not inspect.isfunction(value)
                and not inspect.isgenerator(value)
                and not inspect.isgeneratorfunction(value)
                and not inspect.ismethod(value)
                and not inspect.ismethoddescriptor(value)
                and not inspect.isroutine(value)
            )
            return self.default(d)
        return obj

class U:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    def __init__(self, x, y, z) :
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class N:
    t = [U(0,0,0), U(3.14,0,0)]
    q = 3
    def __init__(self, t, q) :
        self.t = t
        self.q = q

obj = N([U(3.14, 0, 0), U(0, 3.14, 0)], 3)
jsonObj = json.dumps(obj, cls=ObjectEncoder, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
print(jsonObj)
JsonTest.simulate(n=jsonObj)
```

This is the JSON rtepresentation printed by that code

```
{
  "q": 3,
  "t": [
    {
      "x": 3.14,
      "y": 0,
      "z": 0
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 3.14,
      "z": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the Q# code

```
namespace json.test {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    newtype U = (
        x : Double,
        y : Double,
        z : Double  
    );

    newtype N = (
        t : U[],
        q : Int
    );

    operation JsonTest(n : N) : Int {
        let r = n::q * Length(n::t); // just do sometinhg
        Message($"t = {n::t}  q = {n::q}");
        return r;
    }
}
```

Does Q# actually support JSON representation of complex objects?

Comment: I also tried to manually encode the complex object in a more Q#-like fashion `([(3.1, 0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 3.1, 0.0)], 3)` but I got always the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Q# supports representing instances of these user-defined types via Python, but not using `dict`s or JSON strings. To use the Q# interface, we need to use `tuple`s instead. If you want a data structure that contains the labels you are using (`x`, `y`, `z` and so on), I would recommend using `namedtuple`s, for example:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

U = namedtuple("U", ["x", "y", "z"])
N = namedtuple("N", ["t", "q"])

obj = N(q=3, t=[U(x=3.14, y=0, z=0), U(x=0, y=3.14, z=0)])
```

such that

```
>>> obj
N(t=[U(x=3.14, y=0, z=0), U(x=0, y=3.14, z=0)], q=3)
```

You can then simply pass this to your compiled Q# program like so:

```py
import qsharp

qsharp.compile("""
open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

newtype U = (
    x: Double, 
    y: Double, 
    z: Double
);

newtype N = (
    t: U[],
    q: Int
);
""")

JsonTest = qsharp.compile("""
operation JsonTest(n : N) : Int {
    let r = n::q * Length(n::t); // just do sometinhg
    Message($"t = {n::t}  q = {n::q}");
    return r;
}
""")

from collections import namedtuple

U = namedtuple("U", ["x", "y", "z"])
N = namedtuple("N", ["t", "q"])

obj = N(q=3, t=[U(x=3.14, y=0, z=0), U(x=0, y=3.14, z=0)])
JsonTest.simulate(n=obj)
```

which returns

```
t = [U((3.14, 0, 0)),U((0, 3.14, 0))]  q = 3
6
```

If you want to use JSON strings, you can create a custom function like so:

```
import json

def N_from_json(data: str):
    """Create N object from JSON-formatted string
    """
    _data = json.loads(data)
    t = _data.get("t", [])
    q = _data.get("q", 0) # Or some other default value of your choosing

    return N(t=[U(**_t) for _t in t], q=q)


jsonObj = json.dumps({
  "t": [
    {
      "x": 3.14,
      "y": 0,
      "z": 0
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 3.14,
      "z": 0
    }
  ],
  "q": 3,
})

obj = N_from_json(jsonObj)
```

Comment: Thank you @Guen **namedtuple** solved my issue! Maybe the error message that explicitly says that a *JSON object* is expected could be improved.

Comment: Thanks @Stefano that is great feedback, if it's not too much trouble would you mind posting that as an issue on our iqsharp repository so our team can have a look? (see https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues) Many thanks!